# Qgis Shortest Path Facility problem

Tags: qgis, shortest-path, crossing

My aim is to calculate the shortest distance between two point layers
One point layer contains Origin points, the other point layer contains Destination points.
Both layers contain more than 100 data points and that's why manual Point to point shortest path makes no sense to me.

Furthermore, the model contains a road layer on which all points are located and also another point layer.
This point layer contains all points where I have crossings of the streets.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to calculate the shortest path for the Origin-Destination layers yet. The Model should match ID 1 of the origin layer to ID 1 of the destination layer and calculate the shortest path for it.
Is this anyhow possible in Qgis? I just found a bath process, but this just can run the whole layer and specific ids can not behead.

Continuing I want to save all point layers (crossings) that are on the shortest path. But this is not as important as the first goal.

Comment: Do you really need to obtain the actual path (geometry) of an OD-pair?

Comment: Yes. I need these O-D-Pairs as an Input parameter for an OR model..